# Understanding reactive programming

Tags: reactive-programming, event-driven

I  am new to the world of reactive programming. I read that once a variable is declared and it points to a continuous changing value, it will automatically update it.
So I wonder what is difference in the gui controls provided by asp.net, java etc. 
Once we enter a new value in the textbox, it will hold the value automatically. Is it reactive programming? Can anyone provide some good tutorials to understand the concept better?

Comment: There's this topic that can add to this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751115/is-it-possible-to-build-a-reactive-application-using-a-non-functional-language

Answer (score 3):

Think of Reactive Programming (also called Dataflow Programming) like a spreadsheet. Changing the value in one cell automatically updates all other cells referencing the first. It "reacts" to changing data.

Using your GUI example... Let's say that the user enters a new value in the textbox. Let us also say that you have two other controls that use that value to display it in two different ways. Once the use enters a new value, those other two controls automatically receive the new value.

Yes, this could also be done with events but there are additional benefits that dataflow provides...

- Automatic parallelism
- True black box components
- Explicit data dependencies

Dataflow and Reactive Programming is also a very "wide" topic, covering various methods to accomplish what I outlined above... be prepared for many different viewpoints.

Matt Carkci

http://DataflowBook.com

Comment: Good answer. I'm also following the book. Some time ago I open this topic and can add to the discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751115/is-it-possible-to-build-a-reactive-application-using-a-non-functional-language

Answer (score 0):

With reactive programming, you can bind to the UI user control not only a value but the result of some computation over it. The last open to you many opportunities. See more info in the readme for my library ObservableComputations:

https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations